# -(void)didBeginContact is not being called. Thoughts?

Tags: objective-c, sprite, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

```
#import "collisionTestMyScene.h"
const static int nodeBitMask = 0x1 << 0;
const static int node1BitMask = 0x1 << 1;;

@implementation collisionTestMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
        w = 0;


            }
    return self;
}
-(void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    NSLog(@"Contact Begin");

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == nodeBitMask) {
        NSLog(@"Node is Body A");
    }
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == node1BitMask) {
        NSLog(@"Node is Body B");
    }
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"block.jpg"];
        node.position = location;
        [node setScale:0.07];
        node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = node1BitMask;
        node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = nodeBitMask;
        node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = nodeBitMask;
        //node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        node1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"block2.jpg"];
        node1.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
        node1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = node1BitMask;
        node1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nodeBitMask;
        node1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = node1BitMask;
        //node1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        [node1 setScale:0.07];


        [self addChild:node];
        [self addChild:node1];
        node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(node.size.width, node.size.height)];
        node1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(node1.size.width, node1.size.height)];
        SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveToX:100 duration:3];
        node1.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        [node1 runAction:moveUp];
        w = 1;

    }



}
```

It is never NSLogging anything. I have tried changing the bit masks, and more. The CGRectIntersects function would work, however it is not accurate enough. Also, the two nodes are in perfect box shapes. What could I be doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that initWithSize is called? Try to put a breakpoint into that method and make sure that the delegate were set.

Comment: Yes, I just checked, it is beign called

Comment: Where are you calling/invoking didBeginContact from?  Are you missing an outlet connection?

Comment: wait what? I just called it in the .m file of the scene

Comment: can you post that code?

Comment: If you have a method, didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact, you have to have something trigger that method.  My guess is you are missing an outlet to it in Interface Builder.

Comment: Shouldn't this method get fired regardless when two sprites collide?

Comment: @BriOnH in Spritekit the physics simulation should call this method

Answer (score 2):

The problem here are the bit masks. The two nodes are in different category, contact and collision groups (bit masks). Therefore they will not contact nor collide because the bitmasks are compared with `AND` and only if the result is non-zero will the contact/collision occur.

In short, put them in the same contact bit mask at the least, in order to receive `didBeginContact` messages.

Comment: Thank you, however even with all of the bit masks the same, it still does not seem to work.

Comment: oh I just noticed, at the time you assign the bitmasks the physics body is still nil because you create the bodies only after changing the bitmasks, so they'll hav default values.

Comment: Wow. That makes PERFECT Sense! I will try that and let you know ASAP!

Comment: Ok, good, so now it IS registering a collision, however the two sprites are glitching around the screen and not moving to the correct spots. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for my mis-information.  If the post answers your question please mark the question as the answer by clicking the green check mark under the up and down arrows to the left of this answer.  Glad someone could help you!